# python and or statement not working

Tags: python

```
if hello > 2 and < 55:
    print hello
```

Why doesn't this peace of code work? I know it's really basic but I cannot understand or find an answer on the internet why this isn't working, despite looking for the last 20 minutes.

This is python version 2.7.3.

Comment: That's not how boolean logic works; it is not an English sentence.

Answer (score 3):

It should be (well one way of doing it):

```
hello = 3
if 2 < hello < 55:
    print hello
```

Comment: Protip: This is a nice feature in Python, but this does not work in many other languages, this is like the #1 reposted question for new C++ programmers! (@anon you are perfectly correct btw, just thought in case someone saw this in the future I should forewarn them).

Answer (score 1):

```
if hello > 2 and hello < 55:
    print hello
```